# How can I test that Django QuerySets are ordered by PK ascending

Tags: python, django

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta(object):
        ordering = ('pk', )
```

I want to test that this ordering is working as I expect.

```
def test_respect_ordering(self):
    Foo.objects.create(name="bar", pk=2)
    Foo.objects.create(name="baz", pk=1)
    results = Foo.objects.all()
    self.assertEqual("baz", results[0].name)
    self.assertEqual("bar", results[1].name)
```

Although this works as I expect, my test passes regardless of the Meta class or the ordering property defined in it. Is there some way I can test that this code matters?

*Why do I want to test this?* My tests run in SQLite, but production is in mysql. Hopefully someday, we'll use a better RDMBS, and maybe results won't be returned by PK across all of these RDMBS's.

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.ordering) indicate that sorting doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: If you set `ordering = ('name', )`, your test should fail shouldn't it?

Comment: that would fail it, but removing it from Meta does not fail the test, which is what I am trying to prove...

Comment: Removing it from Meta means your database will order by pk by default, so I'm not surprised it passes...

Comment: I like this way of doing it https://stackoverflow.com/a/51939953/1649917 - Checking if the meta component of the class contains the ordering you expect

Comment: There also is queryset.ordered: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.ordered

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the `ordering` attribute in your `Meta` class, the resulting generated SQL query will not have an `ORDER BY` clause (well, in 1.4 anyway). This means you can't rely on the order of the rows.

Unordered SQL queries will generally have an order that looks like it makes some sense. That's because the query plan will most likely use indexes to decrease query time, and indexes can play a big part in the row order for unordered queries. A table generated by a Django model will only have an index on the primary key unless otherwise specified, so in general the 'unordered' order will be quite similar to the order when sorted on primary key.

However, there is absolutely no guarantee here, and this order cannot be relied on. The query plan depends largely on the database engine, and it can even change drastically for very similar queries on the same engine.

If you want a particular order, you should explicitly specify the order you want. That's the only reliable way to guarantee a particular order.

Comment: yes that's exactly why I'm adding that to my Meta. But how can I prove it is necessary through a test?

Comment: I can't give you any definite answer on that, it simply depends on too many factors. You'll have to find a counterexample to your specific setup. Each data alteration (insert, update, delete) will increase the complexity of your table and increase the likelihood of an unexpected result order.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question. But for anyone that comes across this in the future, the approach i would suggest while been crude actually does test the ordering of the queryset in a django model.

#### models.py

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta(object):
        ordering = ('name')
```

#### test_models.py

- the test here are written in pytest, but the logic can be used with the unittest module too.

```py
import pyest
from myapp.models import Foo

@pytest.fixture
def foo_1():
    return Foo.objects.create(name="ZZZZ")

@pytest.fixture
def foo_2():
    return Foo.objects.create(name="AAAA")

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_foo_ordering(foo_1, foo_2):
    foos = Foo.objects.all()
    # this checks that the name attribute second item in the queryset
    # should be greater than first item name attribute in the queryset.
    assert foos[0].name < foos[1].name
```

This idea can be extended to test for other attributes that are used for the ordering in any django model.