# Testing 'class Meta' in Django models

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, django-testing

How can you test **ordering**, **unique** and **unique_together** in Django models?

Comment: `unique_together` meaning what?

Answer (score 4):

**Ordering** - create a couple of instances, then just check if the order is right. Example:

```
self.assertEqual(list[0], a)
self.assertEqual(list[1], b)
etc
```

**Unique** - create an instance, try to create another one with the same unique field. Assert that there is an exception:

```
with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
    MyModel.objects.create(unique_field=the_same_value)
```

**Unique Together** is the same as **unique**.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the MDN Django Tutorial Part 10, “You should test all aspects of your own code, but **NOT** any libraries or functionality provided as part of Python or Django.”  See [MDN's what you should test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Testing#What_should_you_test). To test what was written by you, you should access the meta attribute of the model class and the model's fields.  For example, having defined the book model as follows:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SETNULL, null=True)
    isbn = models.CharField('ISBN', max_length=13, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together(('title', 'author'),)
        ordering = ['author']
```

The Book model would be unit tested for unique, unique_together, and ordering as follows:

```
class BookModelTests(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestdata(cls):
        #create an author instance and a book instance

    def test_isbn_is_unique(self):
        book = Book.objects.get(id=1)
        unique = book._meta.get_field('isbn').unique
        self.assertEquals(unique, True)

    def test_book_is_unique(self):
        book = Book.objects.get(id=1)
        unique_together = book._meta.unique_together
        self.assertEquals(unique_together[0], ('title', 'author'))

    def test_book_ordering(self):
        book = Book.objects.get(id=1)
        ordering = book._meta.ordering
        self.assertEquals(ordering[0], 'author')
```

Comment: This approach feels a little wrong to me. I prefer the method Jahongir describes. Suppose that we want to test book titles have max length of 200 chars. We could check `Book._meta.get_field('title').max_length == 200` but that's not really what we care about. It's better to test creating a book with a title of 200 chars succeeds but creating a book with title of 201 raises a ValidationError. We can then implement it any way we like - by setting max_length or perhaps by validating in the clean() method. But now we are testing behaviour, not implementation. Anyone else have any thoughts on this?